# What level should I be by the time I face the Warden in Borderlands 2?

Tags: borderlands-2

So I epically failed the first time and it looks like I ended up going the friendship gulag route. The problem is I still cant' beat the warden. I was at level 12 and I was getting absolutely no where, so I left the mission and went and did a few side missions. I am now level 14 and I have a rocket launcher that barely does 1000 damage, am I ready to face him?

Comment: Welcome to Arqade. You should only post one question at a time. If your want an answer to your second question, you should make another post

Comment: The game offers you a hint about this for everything you encounter:  If there's a little skull by its health bar, the game thinks you should run!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While I can not answer your question directly, here's some advice.

Get a sniper rifle or an accurate launcher, and feel free to stay away from W4R-D3N, picking at his eye from afar (from the middle or from the left). This way you won't get swarmed by bots and will still kill it eventually.

EDIT: Considering W4R-D3N's shields, as well as obviously bringing shock weapons, one can use "speshul tactics" - when engaging Loaders, do not let constructor's shields go up by sparing a bullet every 5 seconds or so - you don't need to do any considerable damage, just register a hit. This is, of course, easier on a mouse...

AFAIK, all corrosive weapons can cause corrosive damage over time, if this is what you mean by "acid burn". They can be found aywhere. But do not think that corrosion is a must, an explosive or an accurate physical weapon will still do.

Comment: I disagree about a corrosive weapon not being a must - corrosive weapons deal 150% damage against armored targets, like W4R-D3N. A shock weapon (for his strong, regenerating shields) and a corrosive weapon (to melt the metally nougat center) are both recommended.

Comment: I did not recommend against corrosive. What I meant is +50% is not a gamebreaking bonus. Oftentimes I'd choose an physical sniper rifle over a decent corrosive SMG or an auto pistol - reliable criticals from afar are better than moving up close or hitting constructor's hull.

Answer (score 0):

The WAR-D3N, like all Constructors, is crazy hard to kill unless you hit his eye. I noticed this while trying to kill Constructors with Corrosive DOT with an SMG. It took forever until I shot it in the eye a couple times...suddenly they were easy. Just shoot they eye; the problem is the eye is their crit spot, and everywhere else on their body is resistant to damage (even corrosive isn't great unless it hits the eye). I don't actually recommend using launchers against WAR-D3N, since they can't critical hit.

As far as level, you should be no more than 2 levels below WAR-D3N's level; the damage you and enemies take is scaled directly by level (there's no hidden stats, it's a %), so if you're 5 levels below WAR-D3N he'll deal insane damage to you, and vice-versa if you're over-leveled you'll easily slaughter him.

Comment: I've successfully used a corrosive auto pistol with a stupid, but fun tactic - run right up to a constructor's eye, drop to your knees, spray and pray his health runs out faster than your time :)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend lvl 14 or 15 with shock, corrosive, and explosive weapons. Orc JMR stated that the left or middle are good places to kill it.

The best place is the middle, where no attack can hit you.